# Work around for an aggregate within an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate the sum amount of days in this query per authorization number, but I get an error stating an aggregate function cannot perform on an expression with an aggregate. How can I work around this? There are several authorization numbers and want the min and max dates to provide an accurate result in days.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN DBO.FN_AGE(CL_DOB, AH_ADMDT) >= 18 THEN 'ADULT' 
        WHEN DBO.FN_AGE(CL_DOB, AH_ADMDT) < 18 THEN 'CHILD'  
        ELSE NULL 
    END As AgeGroup,
    COUNT(DISTINCT AH_AUTHNO) AS 'Total AFC Admissions',
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DD, MIN(AH_ADMDT), MAX(AH_DISDT))) AS 'Total AFC Days',
    SUM(AD_UNTAUTH) AS 'Total Units'
FROM 
    PCHAUHPF AS A
    LEFT JOIN
    PCHAUDPF AS P
        ON A.AH_RCDID = P.ADF_AUHID
    JOIN
    GTWAUDPF AS G
        ON G.ADP_AUDID = P.AD_RCDID
    JOIN
    PCHCLTPF AS C
        ON C.CL_RCDID = A.AHF_CLTID
    JOIN
    PCHXSPPF AS X
        ON X.XP_RCDID = P.ADF_XSPID
    JOIN
    PCHCPTPF AS T
        ON T.CR_RCDID = X.XPF_CPTID
WHERE 
    AH_ADMDT BETWEEN '10-1-2013' AND '09-30-2014'
    AND AD_PAYSTS = 'A'
    AND CR_CODE IN ('H2016', 'T1020')
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN DBO.FN_AGE(CL_DOB, AH_ADMDT) >= 18 THEN 'ADULT' 
        WHEN DBO.FN_AGE(CL_DOB, AH_ADMDT) < 18 THEN 'CHILD'  
        ELSE NULL 
    END
```

Comment: You can approach this with either a CTE or subquery, where first you get the MIN/MAX in the subquery, and then use them like regular columns in your outer query to get the SUM()

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the expression that you want is one of the following:

```
SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, AH_ADMDT, AH_DISDT)) AS [Total AFC Days],
```

or:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(AH_ADMDT), MAX(AH_DISDT)) AS [Total AFC Days],
```

As matters of style, I encourage you to use single quotes *only* for string and date constants (and not for column aliases).  And, use the full date part name when using `datediff()`.  That way, you (or someone else) doesn't have to struggle to remember if `MM` is for months or minutes.

Comment: The expression I want is a combination of both above. I like my style just the way it is. I figure sql guys should know DD = days and theirs always "Help" in Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of my suggestion from the comments:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
     MyGroupCol
  ,  MIN(MyDateCol) AS MinDate
  ,  MAX(MyDateCol) AS MaxDate
  FROM MyTables
  WHERE SomeConditions=true
  GROUP BY MyGroupCol
)
SELECT 
  MyGroupCol
, SUM(DateDiff(dd, MinDate, MaxDate))
FROM cte
GROUP BY MyGroupCol
```